# Clearing All Response Headers in NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I understand that I can use one of the following to remove specific headers from the response in NGINX

```
proxy_hide_header
more_clear_headers
```

[proxy_hide_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header)

[more_clear_headers](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_clear_headers)

However, As I mentioned, my requirement is to remove all of the response headers. Above directives will only help in removing specified headers.
Is there any way I can remove all headers before sending the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`more_clear_headers` supports wildcard `*`

so this works for all X-Headers: `more_clear_headers 'X-*';`

While `more_clear_headers '*';` does not work, thanks to user582175. So you have to clean specificly the headers you don't want to have.

But you have to build from source for using `headers-more-nginx-modul`.

Comment: `more_clear_headers '*';` doesn't work:
`nginx: [error] more_clear_headers: wildcard key too short: *`